# Loading a unity webgl Game from a separate immersive game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a two separate webGL games that built with unity. Which can be uploaded to a Game portal website. One of two games is a 3d game, which player can walk around to places and interact with some objects.
When player interact with it, I want to load the other game inside the same page. I want to do this process backwards as well.
I tried to do this with, adding the two games into the same project. I have lot of problems when doing it.

1. Light weight render pipeline settings collides
2. Since the project is a WebGL, It should be a small one one but it does not when I wanted to scale up. (20,30 games)
3. Because of the size, it does not support to the mobile web platform.

Can anyone give me a solution for this? Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at your built WebGL game you'll see an `index.html` file. You will need to take both of your built games and put them in a folder and create a new `index.html` (based off of the ones that your WebGL build contain) that will properly load two `unityInstance`s on the same page.

To accomplish this, you will need to change some of your IDs so that the two scripts don't interact with the same DOM elements; and you will need to change the file paths of your built game so that it can access the game even though it's now in a folder.

It's not an easy challenge, and unfortunately, it might require some trickery to get automated. You could also try loading the WebGL project JavaScript or an `iFrame`.

There is a minimum size that a Unity WebGL project can be (around 10mb), so it's not going to scale up to 20-30 games on a single page. For comparison, a typical webpage is ~2mb nowadays. You are going to have to load them one-at-a-time.

Comment: Hi @Anthony, As per your explanation, I understood this. There will be 3 Html files (Game1.html, Game2.html, and index.html) in the same folder. The immersive game that i'm using to browse games, it will be sending a request to the game1.html to index.html where the path is defined and will call to open the game2.html